# Property of a continuous function that is equal pointwise to a family of point-dependent continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ continuous. Suppose there exist for each $x \in X$ an open neighborhood of $x$, $U_x$, and a continuous function $g_x: U_x \rightarrow Y$ such that $f(x) = g_x(x)$. Is it true then that for any $x$ we can find an open neighborhood $W_x$ of $x$ such that $f|_{W_x} = g_x|_{W_x}$? (If true, does this property have a name?)

The complete context I'm working in also provides a continuous map $p:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $pf = id_X$ and $pg_x = id_{U_x}$ for any $x \in X$. I am curious whether the result is true without the existence of such a map - and why - and if not, then why is it true with such a map.

Comment: Counterexample (assuming $f$ is not constant on any non-empty open set): $g_x(u)=f(x)$ for all $u\in U_x$.

Comment: Ok, now I see the existence of such a $p$ is important - probably precisely to eliminate this sort of counterexample. What about if we have a $p$?

Comment: Then that constrains $g_x$ to be equal to $f(x)$ on $U_x$, because $g_x(u)=p^{-1}(u)=f(u)$ for $u\in U_x$.

Comment: Why would $p^{-1}(u)$ have a single element for $u \in U_x$?

Comment: You are right, $p$ doesn't have to be invertible.